# On $\ker\chi $ , $\: \chi :{\rm Gal}(E,F)\rightarrow S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

Assume $E$ is a splitting field of a separable polynomial of degree $n$,so $E$ must have $n$ district roots $(a_1,...,a_n)$ of the polynomial, if $\phi\in{\rm Gal}(E,F)$ then $\phi (a_i)$ must be one of the $a_j$, now

Consider the homomorphism $\: \chi  :{\rm Gal}(E,F)\rightarrow S_n$

$\chi(\phi_i)=j$

**Question1** : what's the $\ker\chi $?

The kernel is consisting of all those $\phi_i$ that send $a_i$ to $a_1$ and so $i\rightarrow 1$?

Now if I apply the $1st$ isomorphism theorem, I get that ${\rm Gal}(E,F)/\ker\chi $ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$

**Question2**: can I get that ${\rm Gal}(E,F) $ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$, with the $\chi$ homorphism?

(This maybe simple but I am a bit confused right now)

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Shaun but they are closely related, probably in 2 line can be answered, but I am stuck

Comment: I grant you that. It's the main reason I didn't downvote. Nonetheless, you ought to keep the number of questions per post to one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel of $\chi$ consists of all those automorphisms of $E$ over $F$ that leave all $a_i$ fixed. But then these also leave the field $F(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ fixed. By definition of $E$ as a splitting field (as opposed to just some - perhaps bigger - field where the polynomial splits), this is all of $E$. In other words, the only element of the kernel is the identity,  $\chi$ is injective. This also gives a "yes" on the second question.

Comment: ohh of course it takes $a_i$ to $a_i$ and so $i\rightarrow i $, the identity of $S_n$ sends $i\rightarrow i $, for every $i$, don't know why I stuck so bad, this was fairly easy. Thanks a lot !